# How to embed a Java applet?

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, embed

I wrote a simple java applet in NetBeans and am having real trouble getting it embedded.  I take my class file and copy that to the same directory as my html page.  I also put my .jar there. On the html page I do

```
<applet code="ServerStatus.class" width="200" height="200">
Your browser does not support the <code>applet</code> tag.
</applet>
```

But the applet never loads.  The first bit of the long error is:

```
load: class ServerStatusChecker.jar not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerStatusChecker.jar
```

What do I have to do to embed this applet? The top of my MyApplet.java file is

```
package org.me.serverstatuschecker;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener  {
```

My ServerStatusChecker.jar is in the same place as the html file im trying to include it in.  Inside the jar i have folders org/me/serverstatuschecker/MyApplet.class.

EDIT:

The full error message is as follows:

```
 Java Plug-in 1.6.0_31
 Using JRE version 1.6.0_31-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

 ----------------------------------------------------


    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:      org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker :   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:          org/me/serverstatuschecker/ServerStatusChecker : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: Sounds like a classpath reference issue.  The error suggests the class loader is looking for a _class_ named ServerStatusChecker.jar, not a jar file.  Can you elaborate on your web application deployment configuration?  e.g. How is the jar file referenced?

Comment: I edited the main post with more information.  Im not sure exactly what you mean about the deployment.  I am trying to just put the file next to it and have the right applet tag, do I need to do more?

Answer (score 3):

### Directory Structure

- `theappletdir/`

  - `applet.html`
  - `ServerStatusChecker.jar`

### Content of `applet.html`

Then use the script supplied by Oracle to deploy applets and JWS apps.  It is called `deployJava.js` and linked from the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  It will:

- Check the minimum stated JRE version is available for use by applets.

  - If not, help the user to upgrade it.
- Embed & run the applet.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'.',
                      code:'org.me.serverstatuschecker.MyApplet',
                      archive:'ServerStatusChecker.jar',
                      width:200, height:200};
    var parameters = {};
    var version = '1.6';  // or whatever version the code was compiled for 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### New Error

```
UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/MyApplet : 
    Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

When I refer to the [version number list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) it indicates the code is being compiled compatible for a 1.7 JRE, whereas the `version` attribute above indicates the code should be able to  be loaded in any 1.6+ JRE.  The best way to fix this is to use the `source`, `target` `bootclasspath` options when compiling the code.  Specify the first 2 as `1.6` and the last as a path to a 1.6 version `rt.jar`.

Comment: Nice Mr. fancy-javascript example. What no pictures? 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels In this case, a script paints a thousand applets.  Or should that be *"Never before, in the history of WWW, have so many applets, owed so much, to just one script."*  Or maybe .. *"One script to launch them, one script to bind them.."* ;)

Comment: Please see my pseudo-answer question.

Comment: I still get errors when I use this load: class ServerStatusChecker.jar not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerStatusChecker.jar Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerStatusChecker.jar
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/me/serverstatuschecker/MyApplet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: See the **New Error** update to my answer.  Also, please edit stack traces directly into the question, use code formatting and leave a comment for interested parties that the question has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure this is the right track.  I installed JDK6 and went to Properties > Libraries and set my Java Platform to JDK 1.6, but I am still getting the same errors about version.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure this is the right track"*  I can assure you **it is the right approach.** So that makes me wonder why you added *"I installed JDK6"*  ***I never advised that!***

Comment: I suppose I thought it was how I would get the 1.6 version of rt.jar.  I guess I'm confused if I should be trying to compile through netbeans or doing it command line.  When ive used javac to compile before I always got .class and not .jar like I need.  Obviously I am a noob with java, thanks so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: The trick here is that all you really need from the previous version is the JRE, not the JDK.  The JDK contains a lot of parts we don't need for this.  So if you are aiming at 1.6, download a 1.6 JRE, the earlier micro-version the better, then compile using the 1.7 SDK & a `bootclasspath` pointing to the 1.6 `rt.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the HtmlConverter Tool?

http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/htmlconv.html

It creates a HTML code that tries to load your applet properly with the Java Plugin.

Comment: I can't actually find the download on that page.  It says hit continue, but all i see is download so I hit that, which leads me to a page that doesnt have it.

Comment: Until Java 6 version, the HtmlConverter comes with the Oracle/Sun JDK. Try to find it with your instalation. If you could not find, please, say to us.

Comment: would it be in java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin?  I cant find it anywhere in the jdk folder

Comment: @DavidFeitosa  Sun gave up supporting the HTMLConverter in favor of `deployJava.js` quite a while before they were bought by Oracle.  Look at my answer for more details.  Also, please don't link to the JavaDocs for an obsolete JRE.  Advice changes, times change - 1.5 is about to go into obsolescence, let alone 1.3!

Comment: @james HTMLConverter is not in java 7.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Good to know that. I have used the HTMLConverter a long time ago and had no problems with it. Any new documentation link for the deployJava.js ?

Comment: How much newer than the link to the [version 7 docs on `deployJava.js`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) do you need?